# C# MVC Calling a method in different path using AJAX

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a HomeController in my ASP.NET MVC application in folder "Controllers". My View is in: "View/Home/Index.cshtml" (look at my figure below).

I am using Ajax to get some json file every a few second. Problem is in Ajax URL, because I really don't know and didn't find, how to tell that property, that it has to go back a few folders and then find the HomeController.

My Solution looks like this:

[image: Solution of my MVC Application]

Here is a method in my HomeController:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetRandomFeed()
{
    Item i = ss.getRandomFeed();
    return Json(new { Source = i.Media.Source, Avatar = i.User.Avatar, Text = i.Text, Name = i.User.Name }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

My AJAX in the View:

```
setInterval(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type:        "GET",
            url:         '/HomeController.cs/GetRandomFeed', // Of course I have tried a lots of attempts in here
            contentType: "application/json;", // Not sure about this
            dataType:    "json",
            success: function (response) {
                console.log("Success :)");
            },
            error: function() {
                console.log("Error!");
            }
        });
    }, 2000);
```

All I want to get that JSON file (or can be even an array of strings) and use it in my Success function. It is a simple Slide Show and JSON contains the URLs that I want to show in the page every X seconds (just changing source of an image that is in that JSON file).

I couldn't find anything like this. How to use that URL correctly OR found something similiar for WebForms but cannot use it in MVC.

Comment: change url to `'/Home/GetRandomFeed'`

Comment: `url: '/Home/GetRandomFeed'` use this

Comment: `url: '@Url.Action("GetRandomFeed", "Home")'`

Comment: Thank you guys. The Home fixed the problem. The '@Url.Action("GetRandomFeed", "Home")' I didn't try, but as I can see, it is very similiar. Very simple and yet, couldn't find the mistake.

Comment: @Stepan You should read up on how the .NET MCV framework is used, especially in regard to controllers and actions. Your problem is elementary and you will run into more stuff like this if you do not do proper preparations.

Comment: @Glubus well to be honest, I have spend looking for this a really long time (lots of hours searching etc...) I have seen the "Home" but always that was a different case and thought that "this is something else". But yes, I need to learn a lot of things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your AJAX URL declaration to:

```
url: '/Home/GetRandomFeed'
```

Remove the **.cs**

Or you can also do, assuming this view is under your controller:

```
url: '@Url.Action("GetRandomFeed")'
```

Comment: Its `/Home/..` not `/HomeController/..`

Comment: The: `url: '/HomeController/GetRandomFeed'` didn't work. But thanks anyway. It works with the "Home" word like in comments in first post.

Comment: Ooops sorry. I am used to Url.Action. I updated my code @StephenMuecke. Kindly check my updated answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, it doesn't seem enter the function is just because the JSON return from the controller doesn't include Status = "OK"

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetRandomFeed()
{
...
...
return Json(new
            {
                Status = "Ok", ...
}
```